# Remove comma separator

Tags: crystal-reports

In my Crystal Reports Viewer control, the report groupes by a field (i.e. `project id = 100061`). However it displays in the group tree view with comma separator like `100,061`. How can I remove this?

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the Field, choose *Format Field*.

In the *Number* Tab, click *Customize* button, then un-check the **Thousand Separator** checkbox in the *Number* Tab.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the Field, choose Format Field.

[image]

In the Number tab

[image]

Click on OK..